# Get HTML Element - Obj-c

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview

I have a web view and some html that looks like this

```
<li>
    <a herf="/reference.dca?iigg=23789d2a9000efd0d80a176ebbaf48d5&zzxx=4945271518265d2358b075c3af020e38&cdx=logoff&userLevel=3"> Logoff </a>
</li>
```

And I am trying to click this button with something like this

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClass('li')[0].click();"];
```

But I can't get it to work, how can I click this button?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClass` is not a function, you should use `getElementsByTagName`.